# Intellij structural search and replace for all forms of if statements

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I wrote a search like this:

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement($sql$);
$code1$;
$resultSet$ = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); 
$code2$;
if ($resultSet$.next()) {
    $code3$;
}
```

And a replace like this:

```
try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement($sql$)) {
    $code1$;
    try (ResultSet $resultSet$ = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
        $code2$;
        if ($resultSet$.next()) {
            $code3$;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, it finds code that has an `if { foo } else { bar}` structure.  I'm fine with this, but the problem is it removes the `else { bar }` part if I replace.  I'd like this search/replace to work sensibly on if statements with an else, multiple else-ifs, or any mixture of these.    Is there a way to do this with one search and replace?

I tried changing the `if` in the search to have an else and that fixed the issue, but then it skips the code that only has an if without an else.

Comment: This looks like a bug. You may want to file a bug report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to do this with a **single** Structural Search & Replace. You can however do it with two. You already have the pattern for finding `if`s with and `else` working. For finding `if`s without an `else` branch, you can use a pattern like this:

```
PreparedStatement $preparedStatement$ = $connect$.prepareStatement($sql$);
$code1$;
$resultSet$ = $preparedStatement$.executeQuery(); 
$code2$;
if ($resultSet$.next()) {
    $code3$;
} else $nothing$
```

Where the constraints (under the *Edit Variables* button)  on the `$nothing$` variable are:
 min/max occurrences: `0, 0`

And using a replace pattern omitting the `else` branch:

```
try (PreparedStatement $preparedStatement$ = $connect$.prepareStatement($sql$)) {
    $code1$;
    try (ResultSet $resultSet$ = $preparedStatement$.executeQuery()) {
        $code2$;
        if ($resultSet$.next()) {
            $code3$;
        }
    }
}
```